# RequestMapping to accept all urls in Rest Apis

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a Controller which is designed to accept all requests and do all the required processing. However it is not working for all requests. My Controller is such:

```
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class GatewayDummyController
```

and my web.xml configuration is:

```
<servlet-name>sample-apis-servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>sample-apis-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The name of the war is sampleApi. I am able to access urls:

```
localhost/8080/sampleApi 
localhost/8080/sampleApi/rest
```

the URL that I cannot access is:

```
localhost/8080/sampleApi/rest/v1.
```

I need to access all urls after `sampleApi/`. Please suggest a way to do that.

Comment: `@RequestMapping("/**")`

Comment: Do you mean you want to find out what all URL's are available under sampleapi/  ?

Comment: Thanks I found the answer after posting this question.

Comment: You can post the same, to answer your own question - This will help others know the answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

Add @RequestMapping("/**") to the controller to accept all urls